# Visual Studio 2022 - text editor rendering issue

Tags: visual-studio, text-editor, visual-studio-2022

Has anyone experienced that Visual Studio 2022 has problems rendering the text with colors and formatting when files are a bit larger?

Check out this movie clip that shows what is happening.

https://igshare.lindab.com/hb/vs2022.mp4

/Henrik

Comment: "a bit larger" I'm guessing that file is the getting towards 10,000 lines. That's huge. No wonder VS is struggling to keep up. The fix is likely to be not having such huge files!

Comment: actually is is 3800 lines. Just checked :)

Comment: That is still a lot of code

Comment: yes, but it happens on pages at around 250 lines. So it must be something else